# fspecial alternatives for Gaussian filter

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, gaussian

I am attempting to use a MATLAB script that requires the use of the Image Processing Toolbox function `fspecial()`.

I do not have the Image Processing Toolbox, but do have the Signal Processing Toolbox which contains suite of tools for the creation of filters. Sadly, I am largely ignorant on filter creation and am looking to see if I can get some help determining if I can replicate the following line of code using the filter creation tools in the Signal Processing Toolbox:

```
fspecial('gaussian', [5 1], 0.75)
```

Answer (score 1):

`fspecial()` creates a set of user-specified two-dimensional filter functions, and provides a set of default values.

The following function will produce the equivalent 2D Gaussian function. It is also the implementation in `fspecial` when run with the option `'gaussian'.`

You can call it by `h = gaussian2D([5 1], 0.75);`, for your example.

```
%% 2D Gaussian filter
function h = gaussian2D(siz, std)

% create the grid of (x,y) values
siz = (siz-1)./2;
[x,y] = meshgrid(-siz(2):siz(2),-siz(1):siz(1));

% analytic function
h = exp(-(x.*x + y.*y)/(2*std*std));

% truncate very small values to zero
h(h<eps*max(h(:))) = 0;

% normalize filter to unit L1 energy 
sumh = sum(h(:));
if sumh ~= 0
    h = h/sumh;
end
```